# C++) E0349 no operator matches these operands occured

Tags: c++, vector, overloading, operator-keyword

I wanted to make scalar * vector operation like 5 * (2,3) = (10,15).

e0349 - no operator matches these operands has been occured after running as below.

But I don't know what's wrong in there.

Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vector {
public:
    Vector();
    Vector(float x, float y);

    float GetX() const;
    float GetY() const;

    static Vector operator*(const float x, const Vector b); //Scalar * Vector operation

private:
    float x;
    float y;
};

int main() {
    Vector a(2, 3);
    Vector b = 5 * a; //Error's here ! 


    cout << a.GetX() << ", " << a.GetY() << endl;
    cout << b.GetX() << ", " << b.GetY() << endl;
}

Vector::Vector() : x(0), y(0) {}
Vector::Vector(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y) {}

float Vector::GetX() const { return x; }
float Vector::GetY() const { return y; }

Vector Vector::operator*(const float a, const Vector b) {
    return Vector(a * b.x, a * b.y);
}
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make `operator*` a non-member function here, and since you're accessing the `private` members in it, you can mark it as `friend`.

```
class Vector {
public:
    Vector();
    Vector(float x, float y);

    float GetX() const;
    float GetY() const;

    friend Vector operator*(const float x, const Vector b); //Scalar * Vector operation

private:
    float x;
    float y;
};

...

Vector operator*(const float a, const Vector b) {
    return Vector(a * b.x, a * b.y);
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lhkQMCzxRlxYLjsY)

Or (without making it `friend`)

```
class Vector {
public:
    Vector();
    Vector(float x, float y);

    float GetX() const;
    float GetY() const;

private:
    float x;
    float y;
};

Vector operator*(const float x, const Vector b); //Scalar * Vector operation

...

Vector operator*(const float a, const Vector b) {
    return Vector(a * b.GetX(), a * b.GetY());
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZFFKi4HTkRND9bwt)